# Is Microsoft Test Manager 2015 compatible with TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

Is MTM 2015 compatible with TFS 2010?  When I try to add my TFS Server to MTM 2010 it won't connect.  As far as we can tell we have added the URL correctly.

It presents the below error:

> Unable to connect to server ' Business
>   Systems'.  Check that the server name is correct and that you have
>   access to the server.
>
> Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the
>   server. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 200: OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know we used MTM 2013 with TFS 2010 so I would expect this to work as well.  Based on the error it looks like the server URL you are using includes the team project or collection name "Business Systems".  Try removing that from the end of the URL.  You want the base TFS server address only.

Comment: Thank you Chief, I've tried that and it's providing the same error, using the syntax http://servername:80/
So I'm assuming then that this is probably access rights?
Also, it amuses me that you're in Birmingham, AL and I'm in Birmingham, England :)

Comment: I would assume its a rights issue then.  .NET/Microsoft must have a big community in Birmingham, England as I often see folks from there.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes it seems to have been rights.  Finally managed to sledge-hammer my way in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great to hear.  If this post was helpful don't forget to mark it as the answer and vote it up.  Thanks!